# Use python to launch programm in 'terminal mode' and add commands

Tags: python, subprocess

I use the subprocess module to launch a programm in "terminal mode" by adding a flag after the executable like this:

```
subprocess.call(nuke + " -t ")
```

This results in the terminal mode, so all following commands are in the context of the programm (my guess is that it is the programms python interpreter).

```
Nuke 11.1v6, 64 bit, built Sep  8 2018. Copyright (c) 2018 The Foundry Visionmongers Ltd.  All Rights Reserved. Licence expires on: 2020/3/15
>>>
```

How can I keep pushing commands to the interpreter from my python script that launched the terminal mode?
How would you quit this programms interpreter from the script?

EDIT:

```
nuketerminal = subprocess.Popen(nuke + " -t " + createScript)
nuketerminal.kill()
```

terminates the process before the python interpreter is loaded and the script is executed any idea on how to solve this elegantly without a delay?

Comment: [`subprocess.Popen` + `.communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) is the recommended way.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog post that as answer, and elaborate if possible. I've just learned something.

Comment: nuketerminal = subprocess.Popen(nuke + " -t") followed by nuketerminal.communicate("nuke.allNodes()") doesn't seem to work. Launching nuke takes quite some time because it needs to check licenses. Maybe communicate() already sends the command before the interpreter is ready? Or did I do some nonesense regarding the commands?

Comment: A catch is that `communicate` only returns when the child process terminates, so all inputs must be provided in one go, which may not suit your needs. Also it requires **binary** input data, with newline characters at the end of  each line. If you need to generate the input procedurally, e.g. tell `nuke` to quit if a condition in the Python script is satisfied, you might need to pipe to its `stdin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = subprocess.Popen([nuke, "-t"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE) # opens a subprocess
p.stdin.write('a line\n') # writes something to stdin
line = p.stdout.readline() # reads something from the subprocess stdout
```

Not syncing reads and writes may cause a deadlock, f.e. when both your main process and subprocess will wait for input.

You can wait for the subprocess to end:

```
return_code = p.wait() # waits for the process to end and returns the return code
# or
stdoutdata, stderrdata = p.communicate("input") # sends input and waits for the subprocess to end, returning a tuple (stdoutdata, stderrdata).
```

Or you can end the subprocess with:

```
p.kill()
```

Comment: `p.wait()` will wait for the process to end and return the return code.